# Conditionally focus left split or previous tab

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

I would like to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> for two different commands, depending on the context.

If there is a split left to the currently focused split, focus it:

```
nnoremap <c-h> <C-w>h
```

Otherwise, focus the previous tab:

```
nnoremap <c-h> gT<cr>
```

How can I express this condition in my `~/.vimrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to check window number with `winnr()`. If number didn't changed, there's nothing to the left any more and previous tab will be selected.

```
function! LeftOrPrevTab()
  let win_no = winnr()
  wincmd h
  if win_no == winnr()
    normal gT
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-h> :call LeftOrPrevTab()<CR>
```